# Seaborn distplot will not handle values all the same

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

```
sns_plot = sns.distplot(kwargs["histogram"], kde_kws=dict(linewidth=2.5), ax=axes[1, 2])
```

with data:

```
[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
```

yields the following error

```
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Which is likely for the kde fitting, but is there a way to force the distplot to handle this for example to not display the density curve but the raw data and of course, to not error. Any good solutions for this rather than resorting to another plot?

Comment: You cannot perform a kernel density estime from a single value. To turn kde off you can use `kde=False`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  wasn't expecting the error to be (not) handled. Good tip though for switching off kde. I'll just put some logic to check for single values.